# jQuery ajax abort after request sent

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Probably best to revise the question:

I have an ajax call in my code and I want to cancel the call immediately after it is sent. Basically, I don't want to wait for a response, I just want the entire request to be sent from the client.  Could anyone provide some ideas on how to accomplish this?

I have tried the following in Chrome, however it seems that the request is never actually sent (I am logging received requests on the server side).

Basically:

```
var sendRequest = jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/awesomeness.txt',
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout: 2000,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {}
});

sendRequest.abort();
```

I have also tried setting a timeout of 1, but bizarrely if I load the page from a new browser the request is not sent (if I refresh the page it is sent).

Answer (score 3):

As easy as just:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '/awesomeness.txt',
    dataType : 'json',
    timeout: 2000,
    cache: false,
    afterSend: function() {/*run awesome code*/}
    success: function(result) {}
});

// call whatever you want after send
afterSend();
```

So there is no built in jquery.ajax event for that but you may just call the function right after `$.ajax();`

Answer (score -1):

Just call `YOUR_COOL_FUNCTION` after your code block.

This will work because ajax requests use callbacks, so it will not block the current execution for the sake of the performed request, but it will make the request, then move on to your code, so it's as simple as putting any desired block of code after this AJAX call.